# Want to apply 50% discount on download product within 2months of expiration in Nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

My shop contains downloaded product with expiry date. So, I want to apply 50% discount on that product if customer purchase it again within 2 month of expiration.

I have used NopCommerce version 2.80.

So how to do this? Please give me suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Please could you give me a suggestion of **what your code looks like**. It's like asking 'How do i fix this?' without saying what i'm meant to be fixing! Please share your code.

Comment: Nopcommerce provide some discount related plugins. but I want to apply discount only on that product which will re-order within 2 months of its expiration. So how would I achieve?

Comment: Providing relevant code for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the solution.

I have implemented my custom code for 50% discount on that product if customer purchase it again within 2 month of expiration at the ApplyDiscountCoupon() ActionMethod of Nop.Web.Controllers.ShoppingCartController. and also I have used "Customer had previously purchased one of these product variants-plugin" of NopCommerce.

Here is a [link](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1442172) to the discounts (promotions) section in the nopCommerce documentation.

So, While when customer apply coupon code at that time it checks for it eligibility and based on that provides 50% discount.